# AS3: Is it an faster way to update the bitmap by ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

-I am making an emulator by AS3,I've nearly finished it,but some efficient problem bothers  me.
  -By using  setPixel method,the redraw seems very slow,I know that it is not the best way to achieve it by AS3.
  -I just wonder whether some better way to speed it up?

```
    for (var a:int = 0; a<8; a++)
{
    color = 0;
    if ( vram&1 ) color = 0x0000FF00;
    setPixel(k, j, color);
    k++;
    vram = vram >> 1;
}
```

Comment: You should lock the bitmap data before the loop and unlock it after.

Comment: You are totally right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how much this will speed things up, but using lock() and unlock() in combination with copyPixels() instead of setPixel() should be faster.

Start by creating a 1x2 BitmapData instance, which you can use as a buffer. Have the left-most pixel at 0x0 and the right-most at 0x0000FF00. That way you could simply copy the appropriate pixel from the buffer.

This way you also remove the overhead of setting the color variable 8 times for each call to the function it resides in.

Here's a general idea of what I mean, don't forget to fill in the appropriate values for alpha if you intend to copy that as well

```
// Instantiate these once only(!)
// Preferably in the constructor or an init functin
var buffer:BitmapData = new BitmapData(2,1);
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,1,1);
var p:Point = new Point();
```

And here's the code

```
lock();

for(var a:uint = 0; a < 8; a++)
{
    // Select what color to copy, i.e. it's position in the buffer
    rect.x = (vram&1) ? 1 : 0;

    p.x = k; p.y = j;
    copyPixels( buffer, rect, p );
    k++;
    vram = vram >> 1;
}

unlock();
```

Comment: great!Because 8 times are not the total loops,should it be much faster if I lock and unlock the entire frame?

Comment: It depends on how big the loop is really and how much is going on outside of it that's accessing the BitmapData. What lock() does is it prevents the BitmapData from being rendered until unlock() is called

Comment: :It obviously speed up my redrawing. But I am still invesgating the better way for faster.How about use SetVector ?  I've tried          var vram:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(total,true); But it prompt WARNING 'static-link-runtime-shared-libraries' is not fully supported.

Comment: Oh,copyPixels is faster than SetVector,Finally prove your code is the best:-)